# Planning solo projects when you are the client

Tags: planning, project-management-style, small-projects

I work on my own doing Rails development. I'm interested to know how others plan their projects when there is no client involved. When building a site that you've thought up yourself, how do you manage your ideas, your software's potential features, and plans for implementation? I've just been taking notes in Evernote and keeping a project journal, but my notes are pretty disorganized, and I'd like to hear of some other workflows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the effective system methodology for doing a start-up project?](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/what-is-the-effective-system-methodology-for-doing-a-start-up-project)

Comment: Hi & welcome to PMSE. Have a look at the [tour] page to check out how this site works. Your question is quite broad (and might be closed therefore). Could you go into detail which problems you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

Start small, and don't try to overcomplicate the process. Try using a tool like [Trello](https://trello.com/) and organize your tasks with a simple [Kanban](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kanban_board) style workflow. Setup some simple lists like:

- Blocked
- Backlog
- In Process
- Testing
- Client Review
- Done